# Set client_id and client_secret in production scripts - R

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-r

While using googleAnalyticsR api, I was authenticating using "ga_auth(token = "my token.httr-oauth") and running scripts in my computer and server perfectly fine. When I ran this scripts in production mode (using CRON), I've started to get this error:

```
"Error: The default Google Cloud Project for googleAnalyticsR is intended 
for evalutation only, not production scripts... "
```

I followed instructions and created my own project, downloaded the json file, and set it before calling library(googleAnalyticsR):

> gar_set_client(json = "/home/path/client_secret_XXXX-XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com.json")
>   2019-11-05 10:41:56> Setting client.id from  /home/path/client_secret_XXXX-XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
>   [1] "my_analytics-export"

I believe I am being unable to tell the API to use this project instead of generic, as I am getting the same error I got at the beginning.

Does anyone knows how??? This is definitely not my thing... and I am running out of ideas!

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new token once you registered your own GCP project.  So move/delete your existing token "my_token.httr-oauth" and then load your client, and recreate your token.

However, if you are using the latest `googleAnaltyicsR` version 0.7.1 then you do not need to create a token, it will create a token under your email.